# PYSNMP custom trap sender, which are those extra oids?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pysnmp

I'm not an snmp expert; I just started some weeks ago in my leisure time to implement a new function in a system of the company.

I copy pasted an answer I found here

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *
from pysnmp import debug

debug.setLogger(debug.Debug('msgproc'))

next(sendNotification(SnmpEngine(),
                      CommunityData('public'),
                      UdpTransportTarget(('192.168.1.92',162)),
                      ContextData(),
                      'trap',
                      [ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.7.8'), Integer32(5)),
                       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.6.7'),Integer32(45))]
                      )
     )
```

My receiver catch 4 varbinds not just 2 like I specified and the debug shows the next

```
2017-03-24 09:07:53,015 pysnmp: running pysnmp version 4.3.4
2017-03-24 09:07:53,016 pysnmp: debug category 'msgproc' enabled
2017-03-24 09:07:54,115 pysnmp: StatusInformation: {'errorIndication': <pysnmp.proto.errind.AccessAllowed object at 0x762eb170>}
2017-03-24 09:07:54,116 pysnmp: StatusInformation: {'errorIndication': <pysnmp.proto.errind.AccessAllowed object at 0x762eb170>}
2017-03-24 09:07:54,120 pysnmp: prepareOutgoingMessage: using contextEngineId SnmpEngineID() contextName b''
2017-03-24 09:07:54,123 pysnmp: generateRequestMsg: Message:
 version=1
 community=public
 data=PDUs:
  snmpV2-trap=SNMPv2TrapPDU:
   request-id=10292983
   error-status='noError'
   error-index=0
   variable-bindings=VarBindList:
    VarBind:
     name=1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0
     =_BindValue:
      value=ObjectSyntax:
       application-wide=ApplicationSyntax:
        timeticks-value=0



    VarBind:
     name=1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0
     =_BindValue:
      value=ObjectSyntax:
       simple=SimpleSyntax:
        objectID-value=1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.1

    VarBind:
     name=1.3.6.1.2.7.8
     =_BindValue:
      value=ObjectSyntax:
       simple=SimpleSyntax:
        integer-value=5

    VarBind:
     name=1.3.6.6.7
     =_BindValue:
      value=ObjectSyntax:
       simple=SimpleSyntax:
        integer-value=45
```

The problem I have is that I don't really know what are the meaning of the first two OIDS.

```
**1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = 0
1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0 = 1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.1**
1.3.6.1.2.7.8 = 5
1.3.6.6.7 = 45
```

looking out seems like they are a OID from the snmpv2-mib but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you are sending a SNMPv2 TRAP (CommunityData([mpModel=1](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.hlapi.CommunityData)) implies). According to the chapter 4.2.6 of [RFC1905](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1905):

> The first two variable bindings in the variable binding list of an
> SNMPv2-Trap-PDU are sysUpTime.0 and snmpTrapOID.0
> respectively.

Since you have not supplied those yourself, pysnmp adds them automatically to produce a well-formed PDU.

Note that, depending on the ID of TRAP you are sending, pysnmp may attempt to find and attach more OID-value pairs to the var-binds as RFC mandates:

> If the OBJECTS clause is present in the invocation of
> the corresponding NOTIFICATION-TYPE macro, then each corresponding
> variable, as instantiated by this notification, is copied, in order,
> to the variable-bindings field.

You can pass a lookup map (["objects" parameter](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.NotificationType)) to initialize those OBJECTS OIDs. Otherwise pysnmp will search them in its local MIB.

Finally, the OIDs you are explicitly passing belong to this part of the RFC:

> If any additional variables are being included (at the option of the
> generating SNMPv2 entity), then each is copied to the variable-bindings
> field.

Comment: Simple perfect answer , thanks a lot, a thanks for the beautiful library.I'm full of doubts but i'm trying myself 100 times before make any question.